# Is there a way to dynamically change the "commands" in manifest from the code in MS Message Extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a message extension running on Microsoft Teams

So, here in the image below, I am signed out

[image]

My question here is how I can update the **Sign Out** to **Sign In**?

Is there a way to add the new command as **Sign In** from the code and remove **Sign Out**?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't do that without the actually updating the app.
However you can add command "Settings" that pops a task window and inside that window you can show "Log in" or "Log out" based on the user's auth state.
Alternatively you can add bot commands "/signin" and "/signout" and control your auth state using these commands.
Hope this helped.